# Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined - during writing my own dataProvider

Tags: react-admin

I have my own Rest API I want to connect react-admin to, so I write my own dataProvider to be able to do that.

However during GET_LIST I got "Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined" error, and I don't find where it comes from.

Below I pasted the dataProvider I wrote.

The data I get is a valid JSON, with { data: [ ... ] } format, but i cannot transform the HTTP response back to react-admin to make it visible on my page (I get the above error message).

```
import { GET_LIST, fetchUtils } from 'react-admin';
import { stringify } from 'query-string';

const apiUrl = 'http://xxx.yyy.zz/api/v1';

export default (type, resource, params) => {
const convertDataRequestToHTTP = (type, resource, params) => {
    switch (type) {
        case GET_LIST: {
            url =  `${apiUrl}/${resource}`;
            break;
        }
    };

    const convertHTTPResponse = (response, type, resource, params) => {
        const { headers, json } = response;
        switch (type) {
            case GET_LIST:
                return {
                    data: json,
                    total: parseInt(
                        headers
                        .get('content-range')
                        .split('/')
                        .pop(),
                        10
                    ),
                };
            default:
                return { data: json };
        }
    };

    const { fetchJson } = fetchUtils;
    const { url, options } = convertDataRequestToHTTP(
        type,
        resource,
        params
    );
    return fetchJson(url, options).then(response =>
        convertHTTPResponse(response, type, resource, params)
    );
    };
};
```

Comment: Is this the exact code you're using? It does not seem right

Comment: in the meantime I realized that the problem was with howthe API sends the data back, so I modified it.

Comment: @RekaKarolyi can you please share your solution?

Comment: It seems to be caused by `validateResponseFormat` in fetch. When an options request is triggered prior to a put it provides an empty response and cannot be parsed.